# Writing to GCS from dataflow based on windowing and element count

Tags: java, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub, dataflow

I am attempting to implement a solution where I need to write data (json) messages from pubsub into GCS using dataflow. My question is exactly similar to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48232113/writing-to-gcs-with-dataflow-using-element-count/51940190#51940190)

I need to write either based on windowing or element count. 
Here is the code sample for writes from the the above question:

```
windowedValues.apply(FileIO.<String, String>writeDynamic()
        .by(Event::getKey)
        .via(TextIO.sink())
        .to("gs://data_pipeline_events_test/events/")
        .withDestinationCoder(StringUtf8Coder.of())
        .withNumShards(1)
        .withNaming(key -> FileIO.Write.defaultNaming(key, ".json")));
```

The solution suggests using FileIO.WriteDynamic function. But i am not able to understand what .by(Event::getKey) does and where it comes from. 
Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's partitioning elements into groups according to events' keys.

From my understanding, the events come from a PCollection using the KV class since it has the getKey method.

Note that :: is a new operator included in Java 8 that is used to refer a method of a class.